# Controlling non-startup form from another class

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2022

How do you control a form from another class if that form is not the "Startup form:"?

Scenario:
I have a simple application with 2 forms (Form1 & Form2) and a class (Class1). Form1 has two controls (TextBox1 and Button1). Form2 has one control (TextBox1).

Class1 code:

```
Public Class Class1

    Public Sub ChangeTextOnForm1()
        Form1.TextBox1.Text = "Success"
    End Sub

    Public Sub ChangeTextOnForm2()
        Form2.TextBox1.Text = "Success"
    End Sub

End Class
```

Form1 code:

```
Public Class Form1
    Dim Class1 As New Class1

    Public Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        Class1.ChangeTextOnForm1()
    End Sub
    Public Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Dim Form2 As New Form2
        Form2.Show()
    End Sub
End Class
```

Form2 code:

```
Public Class Form2
    Dim Class1 As New Class1

    Public Sub Form2_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        Class1.ChangeTextOnForm2()
    End Sub
End Class
```

If Form1 is set as the Startup Form it calls Class1.ChangeTextOnForm1() on Load and the text in Form1.Textbox1 is changed.

If Form2 is set as the Startup Form it calls Class1.ChangeTextOnForm2() on Load and the text in Form2.TextBox1 is changed.

If Form1 is the Startup Form and I click on Button1, Form2 opens but the text in Form2.Textbox1 is not changed. How do you control a form from another class if the form is not the startup form?

Comment: You need to learn about default instances and either use them or don't you're half using them and that's the problem. Read [this](http://jmcilhinney.blogspot.com/2009/07/vbnet-default-form-instances.html).

Comment: Thank you very much. The solution was as simple as I suspected, but I could not find it.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to open the default instance of Form2 instead of a new instance.

```
Public Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    My.Forms.Form2.Show()
End Sub
```

Comment: You don't need the `My.Forms` part. Just the type name is enough. It's worth noting, in case you hadn't realised, that the startup form is always the default instance of its type.